# Prove that $\int_{B_R(0)}m \ge C>0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution

I don't know how to prove (or disprove) this.

Let $(m_\varepsilon)_\varepsilon$ be a sequence of non-negative functions which can not vanish at any point, there exists $M>0$ such that $\forall\varepsilon$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}m_\varepsilon dx=M$, $\|m_\varepsilon\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)}\le C_1$ (uniformly).

Assume also that there exists $C>0$ not depending on $\varepsilon$ such that $\forall\varepsilon$
$$I_\alpha\ast m_\varepsilon(0)\ge C>0$$

**Then, there exist $R>0$ and $C_2$ not depending on $\varepsilon$ such that
$$\int_{B_R(0)}m_\varepsilon(x)dx\ge C_2>0$$**

where  $I_\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{N-\alpha}}$ and $\alpha\in(0,N)$.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: IF $m$ is nonnegative and does not vanish at any point, doesn't that mean $m > 0$? If so, this means $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : m(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$ has positive measure for some $n$, and so it's intersection with some ball $B$ has positive measure. Then integrate over this ball.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have stated the question in a wrong way.... I have a sequence of functions and I would like to prove that that integral is >0 uniformly w.r.t. $\varepsilon$